# My loop won't finish

Tags: c, loops

I want the user to choose when to finish inputting so i initialized " int finish". But the loop bypasses that.
I have tried while, do while loops but it doesn't do it for me

```
char snails[8][11];

 int count;
 int finish;
 do
 {
     for (count = 0; count < 8; count++)
     {
         printf("Enter the snail's name:");
         scanf("%10s", &snails[count]);
         int timea;
         int timeb;
         int timec;
         int timed;

         printf("Enter %s 's time for the first leg:", snails[count]);
         scanf("%d", &timea);
         printf("Enter %s 's time for the second leg:", snails[count]);
         scanf("%d", &timeb);

         printf("Enter %s 's time for the third leg:", snails[count]);
         scanf("%d", &timec);
         printf("Enter %s 's time for the fourth leg:", snails[count]);
         scanf("%d", &timed);

         int timef = timea + timeb + timec + timed;

         int time1 = timef / 60;
         int time2 = timef % 60;

         printf("%s finished in %d minutes and %d seconds \n", snails[count], time1, time2);
         printf("Type 1 if you have finished inputting or 0 if you have not:");
         scanf("%d", &finish); 
     }


 } while (finish == 0);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Nitpick: `scanf("%10s", &snails[count]);` should be `scanf("%10s", snails[count]);`.

Comment: Because it doesn't check the condition until the end of the `do`-`while` loop. Try having `count < 8 && finish != 0` as the condition in your `for` loop and eliminating the `do`-`while`.

Comment: thanks i had to add && finish == 0  to " count < 8"

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to execute the loop up to 8 times, unless they indicate they are finished:

1.Remove the do while loop.

2.Do one of the following:
change the condition of the for look to:

```
count < 8 && finish != 1
```

or break from the for loop :

```
if (finish == 1) break;
```

then it will execute the for loop until either:

- it does it 8 times
- or they enter 1 when asked if finished